# django equivalent: select * from table where date(convert_tz(date, 'UTC', 'EST')) == date('my_date');

Tags: django

Model table has field 'date' defined as DateTimeField and holds date/time in UTC. Suppose, I'd need to filter rows by particular date, '2014-03-08' in EST. MySQL allows this query:

```
select * from table where date(convert_tz(date, 'UTC', 'EST')) == date('2014-03-08');
```

Couldn't find anything to implement same query in django....

Comment: Mox, that's understood.
r = table.objects.all()
r.filter(date__????(tz1, tz2)=='my_date')
What's supposed to be in "????"

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/ Maybe you can take a look at the documentation on the usage?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Mox, I guess my question was too short and confuses you...